# How to get user information from an IP address?

Tags: ip, information-gathering

A spammer is harassing my friend and she doesn't know who. With some struggle, I found out the spammer's IP address. But I don't know how to proceed after this.

She says she doesn't want to move legally; as she suspects the perpetrator could be in her own family.

How can I get owner information (name, physical address) from a specific IP address?

Comment: Short answer: you can't

Comment: The duplicate is an inverse of your question, but the answers address your question.

Comment: @schroeder Thanks man. So, even if my cause is legally valid, i can't get user info from isp?

Comment: That's a completely different question. You, as an individual, cannot get this information. The ISP, on the other hand, *does* have this information. But they will not give it to you. They may give it to law enforcement. Phoning up the ISP and asking nicely with a story of woe will not give you the info you seek. You are not entitled to it.

Comment: @schroeder ok got it. Tysm